# ViewChild component as undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting my component as undefined. I have it set as a `@ViewChild` and it has a export class. Any help would be great. When I do go to definition I am taking to the correct class `SelectNccnInternalReviewersComponent` but when I debug it I get the error `undefined`

Class I am calling export class

```
    import { SelectNccnInternalReviewersComponent } from "../../Components/Review/SelectNccnInternalReviewersComponent";
        
export class UpdateReviewersPopup implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild(SelectNccnInternalReviewersComponent) selectNccnInternalReviewersComponent: SelectNccnInternalReviewersComponent;

    @Output() reviewersAdded: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

    constructor( @Inject(ReviewService) private reviewService: ReviewService) {

    }

this.selectNccnInternalReviewersComponent.initPotentialReviewers(undefined, undefined, true);
```

Component Class with export class

```
@Component({
    selector: ".select-nccn-internal-reviewers",
    templateUrl: "/Views/Components/Review/SelectNccnInternalReviewersComponent.html"
})
export class SelectNccnInternalReviewersComponent extends SelectableGrid<PotentialMdReviewerDto, string>
```

[Undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ757.png)

Comment: There is not enough information here.. and the snippet you posted seems illogical or incomplete..

Comment: I updated the post with more information

Comment: Check whether you imported everything correctly

Comment: See that ViewChild you can use in `ngOnInit` **only** if you add `{static:true}`**and** if your "child" is always visible in your component -not under a *ngIf-). Else you can get it in `ngAfterViewInit` or if you use in a function that is called when you make (click) in a button. See the docs:https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: What about AfterViewInit? Can I use ViewChild like a function in that too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not importing `ViewChild`

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild